# Adding a column to data.frame and fill that column with a particular string using R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

The data frame looks like

```
y1 x2 x3 x4 x5
2  3  5   2  5
11 13 34  4  4
21 3  45  55 89
```

The study requires to add another column named x1 to this data.frame named x2 and fill all the observations with a particular string z. The output should look like :

```
y1 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
2  z  3  5   2  5
11 z 13 34  4  4
21 z 3  45  55 89
```

Kindly help as I tried searching it on this forum but unable to find it.

Comment: Try, `cbind(df1, x1='z')`

Comment: duplicate question. downvoted you.

Comment: The practically duplicate question was on the first page of Google results using your exact question title as the search string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can just assign the 'z'

```
df1$x1 <- 'z'
```

and then change the order of the columns,

```
df1[c(1, 6, 2:5)]
```

---

Or if this column needs to be created in a particular position, we can use `append`

```
data.frame(append(df1, c(x1='z'), after=1))
#  y1 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
#1  2  z  3  5  2  5
#2 11  z 13 34  4  4
#3 21  z  3 45 55 89
```

Comment: dear ..Many thanks for the kind help. I accept the answer.